# How to connect a new project to GitHub repository?

Tags: git, github

I have just created a new project and added some files there.
Then I have created a new GitHub repository (public).

Now I want to push my local Git project to the remote GitHub.

So I do that:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
```

Then:

```
git remote add https://github.com/user/project.git
git remote -v
# origin    https://github.com/user/project (fetch)
# origin    https://github.com/user/project (push)
```

Then I am trying to push my new project items:

```
git push
# fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
# To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
# git push --set-upstream origin master
```

So I am doing as said:

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
And get back:
# To https://github.com/user/project
# ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
# error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/user/project'
# hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is # behind
# hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
# hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
# hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So I keep following their instructions:

```
git pull
And I get:
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
```

And continue doing what they write:

```
git pull origin master
And get back:
From https://github.com/user/project
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

I have managed this to be working only by using

```
git clone https://github.com/user/project
```

But I do not think that this is the right way of working, is it?

Hope for some tips. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I simply proceed as follows. I don't run `git` on my computer to create a project:

- create the repo on Github
- clone it
- move the obtained `.git` folder (and optionally the `README` file and the `.gitignore` file) to the working folder

Then you're ready for `add`, `commit`, `push`.

Answer (score 1):

You should run this command,
`git remote add origin https://github.com/user/project.git`
not
`git remote add https://github.com/user/project.git`

Comment: That does not working - giving the same error I have mentioned above.

Comment: Then try this, `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories origin/master`. I think you created file like `README.md` or `.gitignore` when you create GitHub repository. But you are trying push without pulling them. Please excuse my poor English.